# The POM for fr.dawan:calculatrice:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: java, maven, github, jenkins, build

I am using Jenkins, Maven, and GitHub. In Jenkins, I fetch the project from the remote repository (GitHub) and execute it (trigger Maven builds).

When I do this, it displays the following error: : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project calculatrice-web:

**Could not resolve dependencies for project fr.dawan:calculatrice-web:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: fr.dawan:calculatrice:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (absent): Could not find artifact fr.dawan:calculatrice:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]**

In my "calculatrice-web" project, I am using the dependency from "calculatrice" Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>fr.dawan</groupId>
    <artifactId>calculatrice-web</artifactId>
    
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>calculatrice-web</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        
         <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.dawan</groupId>
            <artifactId>calculatrice</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <finalName>calculator-app</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>admin</password>
                    <path>/calculator-app</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Could you help me solve the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that maven could not find any artefacts for `fr.dawan:calculatrice:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

This seems to be your own library so it could run fine in your local machine. If you are fetching project from other environments, it would fail because that lib is only available in your machine.

You could try to publish it to your own artifactory and config maven to use that.

Comment: Could you please help me? What are the different steps to publish it to my own artifactory and configure Maven to use that?